# Access elements attributes from different browser give different result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a (very simple) test to access html element attributes from different browser and the results are different.
Everything works in Chrome but...just on it. No Firefox, No edge, no IE and no safari.

So, the problem is how i get the result, i know, `because var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-request="2"]');` creates different objects. For example, using web inspector, in Chrome i've got Attributes tag while in Edge doesn't exist (even the className! is not displayed).

I need to loop inside a variable and can't use `$(#obj).class('attrName')`.
To make myself clear i made a jsFiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackShawarna/qLxqtsqz/

Thanks all of you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i just figured out the most basic thing i could try.

```
Using .getAttribute('nameAttr') made the trick.
```

Comment: yes, each browser will order them differently, where mozilla sorts them by name but chrome does by their location. So on chrome, 4th prop in array is `data-rule`, but on firefox it is `type` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following code a short,

```
$('input[data-request=2]').each(function(index){
    var className = $(this).attr("class");
    var selectID = className.split('_')[2];
    var selectName = className.split('_')[1];
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value'); //data-value 
    var rule = $(this).attr('data-rule'); //data-rule
    var str = selectID + "\n" + selectName + "\n" + value + "\n" + rule + "\nElement Index " + index;
    $("#result").append(str);
    $("#result").append($('<br/>'));
});
```

This JavaScript code gives same result in both Chrome and Firefox.

Use the following HTML structure:

```
<input class="hidden_1_4" type="hidden" data-request="2" data-value="0" data-rule="Equal" />
<input class="hidden_1_4" type="hidden" data-request="3" data-value="0" data-rule="NotEqual" />
<input class="hidden_1_5" type="hidden" data-request="2" data-value="0" data-rule="Equal" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLxqtsqz/1/)